# how solve this error masage related str "this variable must be final to be used in local class"

Tags: java, android

```
public class saeidactivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.saeid);
        Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.saeidbtn1);
        TextView str=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.saeidtxtv1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                 public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    str.setTextColor(0xFF00FF00);
                }

            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Like others said, you can make the textview final or even better, declare the textview inside the click listener if you are only using it there.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `final` modifier.

`final TextView str=(TextView)`
instead of 
`TextView str=(TextView)`

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can make the TextView local.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
     public void onClick(View v)
    {
        TextView str=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.saeidtxtv1);
        if(str != null)
            str.setTextColor(0xFF00FF00);
    }
});
```